# limit upload by extensions in php upload script

Tags: php

I have a working upload file script, now i looking to make script secure by limiting file extension, i don't know how to do that

```
<?php
$extensions = array("docx","pdf","png");
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];      
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
        $desired_dir="uploads";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }

            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="user_data/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
            mysql_query($query);            
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Successfully uploaded";
    }
}
?>
```

Here is form submission method i am using

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" class="btn btn-inverse btn-icon input-block-level" />
<input type="submit" class="save btn btn2" style="padding: 0px; margin: 10px; "/>
 </form>
```

Comment: wow! already 17 mins has passed and I don't  see any warning for OP that not to use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

From [php.net | Handling file uploads](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) :

```
// DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
// Check MIME Type by yourself.
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if (false === $ext = array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    ),
    true
)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}
```

Complete upload code:

**upload.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

try {

    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // You should also check filesize here.
    if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 1000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

---

**upload.html**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="upfile" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Notes**:
1 - `mysql_*` extensions were deprecated long time ago, use `mysqli` or `PDO` [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

2 - `Windows` users must uncomment `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in `php.ini` to enable `Fileinfo` extension. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php) 
(kudos @Jigar)

3 - Make sure a **writable** folder named `uploads` exists on the same dir as the `php`.

Comment: Note: Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll DLL file in php.ini to enable `Fileinfo` extension. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php)

Comment: @PedroLobito, your complete script showing an error = "Invalid parameters." all the time showing this and not storing file into server

Comment: @PedroLobito can you help, this script keep showing "Invalid parameters." on page load and not storing file into server & db

Comment: On your form change from: `<input type="file" name="files[]"...` to: `<input type="file" name="upfile[]"...`  , make sure a folder named `uploads` exists on the same dir as the php file, and is writable. Also change you form `action=""` to match the php script name (`action="upload_ex.php"`). If the html `form` is inside the `php` script, you may have to check if `$_POST` `isset` in order to avoid errors. I've tested the code above and it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Just use`pathinfo()` to get `file extension`

```
    <?php

    $extensions = array("docx","pdf","png");

    $_FILES["file"]["name"] ="file_name.png";

    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);;

    if(in_array($ext,$extensions))
    {
        echo $ext." accepted extenstion";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $ext." this file extenstion not accepted";
    }

    ?>
```

**NOTE:**

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: You should **never rely only on the file extension to check the file type** because it can easily spoofed, you should check the MIME type instead.

Comment: thank you for the info . and i'm going to delete this answer @PedroLobito